# Java Scriptlet double quote escaping problem

Tags: java, string, jsp, escaping, scriptlet

Server side returns String representing following object:

```
value = {"attrName": "attrValue is \"some value\""};
```

Client side/JSP:

Case 1:

```
JSON.parse('<%= value %>');
```

Case 2:

```
JSON.parse("<%= value %>");
```

In `case 1` JSON parse error is generated because JavaScript looks like `JSON.parse('{"attrName": "attrValue is "some value""}');` when `value` gets inserted - JSON is trully invalid.

In `case 2` syntax error is generated because JavaScript looks like `JSON.parse("{"attrName": "attrValue is \"some value\""}");` - `JSON.parse("{"a` messes everything up.

**Problem:** looking for explanation why Strings are inserted in a such way and for a possible global solution (when code changes are not needed for all occurences of `JSON.parse` in the code)

**Update 1**:

Java file generated from case 1 JSP:

```
out.write("\r\nsomeStringsJSON.parse('");
out.print(value);
out.write('" ));\r\nsomeMoreStrings");
```

Java file generated from case 2 JSP:

```
out.write("\r\nsomeStringsJSON.parse(");
out.print(value);
out.write(" ));\r\nsomeMoreStrings");
```

Comment: What string does your Java code actual return?  `value = { ...` isn't valid Java code, nor a valid Java string.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Server side returns a valid JSON. How do I know: a) Google Gson is used to turn List into JSON b) everything works fine as long as double quotes are not introduced into attribute's value. I have written `value = ...` to emphasize that double quotes are correctly escaped in generated JSON

Comment: Your first case looks suspicious to me.  What would those escaped double quotes suddenly become literals, and the literals also remain as literals?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if I understand you correctly then yes, that is exactly what is happening. That is the reason why I am having this issue. Problem is that when JSP engine writes `\"attrValue is \\"some value\\"\"` (using JspWriter.print) it (the engine) for some reason translates that String to `"attrValue is "some value""` (case 1) instead of `"attrValue is \"some value\""` (case 2)